# How to send a msmq message to a remote host? (Rhino ServiceBus)

Tags: msmq, rhino-servicebus

in the course of writing a robust message infrastructure on a windows network, i've decided to use a service bus on top of msmq; since i wanted to keep the overhead at a minimum i went with Rhino Service Bus.

What i have in mind is that any client (4-5 tops) of the service can notify one machine on the network by pushing a message on this machine queue. The message is then processed by a service. So in my mind what i had was something like

- Many clients notify the same remote endpoint
- One service pulls the messages out of the queue and handles them

However i'm having a problem regarding the remote sending; my message simply doesn't appear in the queue. What i checked is

- no error is reported by RSB
- according to what i got from the net, i've apparently left all permissions wide open on the remote machine.
- the remote endpoint looks like it's translated correctly by RSB, with the correct syntax.
- In a network sniffer i see traffic related to MSMQ taking place.
- it's working if all the posting/processing of messages is done on the same machine

I don't really see where to go from there to check where the problem lies. How can i check that the permissions are correct? Are there samples that show out-of-the box remote communications between machines for RSB?

Comment: Why don't you test with sending plain MSMQ messsages? If you enable negative source journaling then you can find out if messages are being discarded as a message will appear in the sender's Dead Letter Queue.

Comment: Sorry, you lost me at negative source journaling. This sounds like sci-fi to me ;) Anyway, i was planning on testing the msmq brick alone so i guess i'll be back with info

Comment: Make sure MSDTC is running and allows connections.  You may have to play with authentication options.

Comment: could you post some config and source?  I didnt see a way that transport from the local msmq was moving  to the remote msmq, either by IPC or msmq<->msmq